# How to update user last visit date in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

I need to update last user visit date, but not only when user login, becouse user can be authenticated a long time with correct session and if he don't logout. Can I do it?

NOTE: I think better to do update last visit with event listener, when framework recheck user session, but I don't know what exactly event listener I need.

Comment: Try subscribing to this event `security.authentication.success`. The event you are expecting is `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent`

Comment: @AlbertoFernández I try to subscribe like `tags: - { name: security.authentication.success, event: onAuthenticationEvent }`, but I don't get `onAuthenticationEvent` method

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, correct one is: `tags: - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.success, method: onAuthenticationSuccess }`